# How to automate clearing Firefox (Fenix) browsing data?

Tags: firefox-for-android

On desktop this is considerably easy: enable the setting to "delete cookies and website data when closing Firefox" in `about:preferences#privacy` and (optionally) schedule a task to kill the browser process whenever desired. Firefox has a similar setting on Android, but one must always manually select 'quit' from the main menu (after enabling [the said option](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Qcn14.png)):

[image: settings screenshot]

I haven't been able to come up with a solution aside from automating touch input (no experience, and I'm already using cron in Termux... or fully clearing the app data with ADB (`adb shell pm clear com.package.name`). Wiping the user data directory in Termux may also be an option, but this requires root rights (last I tried, I apparently bungled up  permissions to some degree).

Comment: Worth noting that Termux can run graphical desktop applications, but I can't say how viable this is with Firefox on most devices.